# What does "Ncat: ." error mean?

Tags: ssh, netcat

I am trying to connect to a SMTP server via port forwarding(using putty). In Tunnels, I have added a source port <-> destination binding as 4025 <-> SMTP_SERVER:SMTP_PORT.

Using putty, I open a session and enter my user/pwd which succeeds. Now on my machine(where putty is installed), I do

```
ncat localhost 4025
```

I get the error "Ncat: .". What does this mean in my context? It's hard to search for this

Answer (score 1):

It means that 4025 port is blocked by the firewall. Creating an inbound rule solved the issue